# Proving Uniform Continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous in $[0,\infty]$ and let $lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ be finite. Then $f(x)$ is Uniformly Continuous in $[0,\infty]$.

I managed to prove that $f(x)$ is boudned in $[0,\infty]$, but I couldn't prove it's Uniformly Continuous.

Can you help me with the proof?

Comment: I guess we can prove it this way........$0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ from the definition of continuity and  let $ x=a+h$ and therefore $0<|h|<\delta \implies |f(a+h)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ This is true for every value of $h$  at the point $a$ and now change the value of $a$ again and again to prove the uniform continuity in the domain.... Any thoughts on this are welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\ell:=\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x).$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. **By definition of the limit**, there is an $M>0$ such that $$|f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$$
if $x\geq M$. Moreover, $f$ is continuous on $[0,M]$ which is compact, and thus it's also uniformly continuous (by [Heine-Cantor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)). So there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $$\forall x,y\in [0,M], |x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon.$$

Moreover, if $x,y\geq M$, we have that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \underbrace{|f(x)-\ell|}_{<\varepsilon}+\underbrace{|f(y)-\ell|}_{<\varepsilon}<\varepsilon+\varepsilon=2\varepsilon.$$

*Remember that by definition of the limit, $|f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$ if $x\geq M$.*

So, in particular, if $x,y\geq M$, and $|x-y|\leq \delta$, we have that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2\varepsilon$$
what prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[M,\infty [$.

Now we have that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,M]$ and on $[M,\infty [$. This unfortunately don't prove (a priori) that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,M]\cup [M,+\infty [=[0,+\infty [$. We have to prove that if $x\in [0,M]$, $y\in [M,\infty [$ and $|x-y|<\delta$, we still have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ (or to be precise, we'll get here $|f(x)-f(y)|<3\varepsilon$, but it doesn't matter. I let you think why !).

So, let $x<M<y$ s.t. $|x-y|<\delta$. In particular, $|x-M|\leq \delta$, $|y-M|\leq \delta$ and thus $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \underbrace{|f(x)-f(M)|}_{\leq \varepsilon}+\underbrace{|f(M)-f(y)|}_{\leq 2\varepsilon}\leq 3\varepsilon$$
what finally prove the claim. In fact, you also have to check the result for $y<M<x$, but it's exactly the same than the case $x<M<y$.

Comment: This is a bit scary for me.... can you explain what are you doing.....I mean the parts where you are comparing x and y with M

Comment: First, do you agree that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,M]$ and $[M,+\infty [$ ? The problem is that it doesn't imply that it's uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty [$. To prove it, we have to prove that if $x<M<y$ is such that $|x-y|<\delta$ then we still have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Can you understand ? If not, I will re-edit my answer.

Comment: No I am not able to understand....Please re-edit your answer @surb

Comment: I hope it's more clear now :-) @Jasser

Comment: This was very much helpful and I now got all of the things you explained (and the difficult part that "Now we have that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,M][0,M$] and on $[M,∞[[M,∞[$. This unfortunately don't prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on$ [0,M]∪[M,+∞[=[0,+∞[[0,M]∪[M,+∞[=[0,+∞[$") Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty]$, it is a continuous function defined on a compact set, so uniform continuity is an immediate consequence. You have to be mindful of the metric you are working with, though. The usual metric on $\mathbb R$ does not extend from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\infty]$, if you use the metric directly, you have to find a different metric from the usual one.

Comment: What are you saying ? If the OP ask this type of question, you can imagine that he ignore every thing about topology compactification... and of course that he mean the standard metric on $\mathbb R$...

Comment: What I am saying is that an easy way to answer this question is to realize that $[0,\infty]$ is a compact set, and then apply a basic theorem about continuous functions on compact sets. I mention the metric only as a cautionary point.

Comment: Your answer is definitely not adapted to the question and should be a comment !

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it a bit more applicable. If you still don't think so, I suppose we will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: In $\mathbb R$, the set $[0,\infty ]$ is not compact !

Comment: But $[0,\infty] $ is not a subset of $\mathbb R $. Under the natural (and metrizable) topology on $[0,\infty] $ is homeomorphic to $[0,1] $, and is therefore compact.

Comment: $[0,\infty ]$ is commonly used as a subset of $\mathbb R$, (and espacially in measure) to denote in particular the fact that that we can write $\lim_{x\to +\infty }...$ But anyways, it's not important !

Comment: Here lies the root of our disagreement. I have always seen $[0,1] $ denote the one point compactification of $[0,\infty) $.

Comment: No ! the root of our disagreement is the fact that it's just a simple problem of analysis and not an exercise of topology that utilizes compactification or other strange topology !